# Un Stack y a continuación un CustomScrollView en Flutter

Tags: flutter

Necesito crear una página comenzando con un Stack seguido de un ListView o CustomScrollView, lo cual siempre me da error. ¿Alguna sugerencia para solucionarlo?

Comment: Buenas, este tipo de preguntas, no tienen cabida en SOes. Las preguntas deben ser relativas a un problema concreto, explicando siempre el proceso que se ha realizado, mostrar el código del error y el código de lo que has intentado. Preguntas del tipo: ¿me hacéis el trabajo? o ¿me hacéis la tarea? normalmente son cerradas, ya que van contra las normas del sitio.

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona el sitio y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona datos de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado.